# How to insert css file in body after webview.addContentScripts

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I use following code to add css file to webview

```
  webview.addContentScripts([
    {
      name: 'myRule',
      matches: ['https://app.yinxiang.com/*'],
      css: {files: ["vendor/bootstrap.css"]},
      js: {files: ["vendor/jq.js", "vendor/keymaster.js", "ctn.js", "find_dialog.js"]},
      run_at: 'document_start'
    }]
  )
```

and in find_dialog.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {`
  $("body").append(`
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/bootstrap.css">
`)
 ...
```

In webview devtool, it raise

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) -- https://app.yinxiang.com/vendor/bootstrap.css
```

How to add vendor/bootstrap.css?

Comment: It says 404 so it's trying to load the file but fails because it can not find it at the url specified: `https://app.yinxiang.com/vendor/bootstrap.css`. The url is most likely wrong. (Is bootstrap.css for example found directly in /vendor?)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're trying to add your local copy of Bootstrap CSS into a page.

However, when you do it by adding an explicit `<link>` element, and give a relative path, it's relative to the page in question (in this case, `https://app.yinxiang.com/`), not to your app.

You can refer to internal app content from a content script if you must, but you have to do 2 things:

- Use an absolute path [provided by `chrome.runtime.getURL()`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#method-getURL) instead of the relative path.
- Declare resources as webview-accessible using the `webview.partitions` manifest key. See [Accessing packaged resources](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#local_resources) in the documentation.

That said, I don't think you need to do this at all; you already declared the CSS as injected along with your content script. It should already be included along with your `find_dialog.js`, so your extra code is superfluous. If it isn't, double-check your (local, relative) path.

Answer (score 1):

I use following way to fix:

in manifest.json, add webivew accessible_resouces

```
  "permissions": [
    "webview",
    "alwaysOnTopWindows",
    "http://*/",
    "https://*/"
  ],
  "webview": {
    "partitions": [
      {
        "name": "static",
        "accessible_resources": [
          "vendor/bootstrap.css"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
```

in find_dialog.js, use chrome.runtime.getURL('vendor/bootstrap.css') to get css full url

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("body").append(`
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="${chrome.runtime.getURL('vendor/bootstrap.css')}">
`)
```

Comment: I'm still curious as to why you need it in the first place. Is the `css` part of `addContentScripts` not working?

Comment: I think `css: {files: ["vendor/bootstrap.css"]}` is useless, I forget to delete it since chrome app doc has this

Comment: Why do you think it's useless?

Comment: even I add `css: {files: ["vendor/bootstrap.css"]}`, I cannot found it in background.html devtool and window.html devtool

Comment: And why would you? It's injected in the webview, not in your app or background window. To inspect THAT you need `chrome://inspect`